# The difference between async loading js files and loading in footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asynchronous, pagespeed

is there a difference between loading js files in a web page header on the header, to simply load them at the footer? I mean from loading time point of view.
1. if so, which is better and why?
2. Does it make a difference from JS scope point of view ? meaning will some dependent scripts will work with one approach rather than the 2nd?
thanks !